# How do I convert a Date to an int?

Tags: date, int, java.util.date

I have this

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
Date date = new Date();
```

I know the value as 10 but have got no idea how to print it out. How do I convert it to an int? If there even is a way?

Answer (score 0):

date.getMonth()

it is deprecated - you should be using Calendar, but if you don't want to change, that'll do it.  It is 0 indexed, so remember to change the resulting value appropriately.

[Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getMonth%28%29)